# Event Highlight in calender depends on dates formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Event calendar Highlighting the dates, but If I have two events on same dates i want it to highlight some different color to Show that this date is having two Events
i use Conditional formatting
`=IF(B6="",FALSE,SUMPRODUCT((B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[Start]"))*(B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[End]"))))`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your conditional format is working, I presume that the calendar stores full fledged dates and not just numbers.

Create two conditional format for same set of cells.

1. `=IF(B6="",FALSE,SUMPRODUCT((B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[Start]"))*B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[End]")))=1)`  -  format with some color.
2. `=IF(B6="",FALSE,SUMPRODUCT((B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[Start]"))*B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[End]")))>1)`  -  format with some other color

Comment: just confirm it will be three conditions in total

Comment: No. just 2 conditions will suffice. you need to modify your existing condition to 1 of the above and add another condition